# How to select last imported object with console?

Tags: scripting, import, command-line, .fbx, csv

I'm writing a script for fast importing with CSV file. There's a lot of things, like location, scale and quaternion rotation. Problem with the location I've already solved, but scale and rotation are still. I'm importing FBX files. I can set rotation in while importing but there's XYZ rotation and scale is proportional.

UPD: Successfully solved scale problem by `bpy.ops.transform.resize`. Now I need to change rotation mode there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the location, rotation and scale of objects without operators:

```
bpy.data.objects['SomeObject'].rotation_euler = (0.1, 0.5, 3.141592/180*50)
bpy.data.objects['SomeObject'].location=(0,0, 0.5)
bpy.data.objects['SomeObject'].scale=(2,2,2)
```

When you import objects from .FBX file the imported objects are usually selected by the importer so you can get the objects by looping through selection:

```
import bpy

sel = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in sel:
    print(obj.name)
```

What you mean by last imported object is up to you. I suppose you could sort the selection somehow. This might not be the most elegant way, so someone please correct me, but it could go something like this if you wanted to sort them alphabetically by name:

```
import bpy

sel = bpy.context.selected_objects

sortedObj = [ [obj.name, obj] for obj in sel]
sortedObj = [obj for name, obj in sorted(sortedObj)]

for obj in sortedObj:
    print(obj.name)
```

Comment: The selected objects is a property that returns a list of the current selected objects, not a reference/. Hence could sort the list in place`sort(sel, key=lambda o: o.name)`.